# SQL query to get counts from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to write a query to combine two tables in order to get desired result set with count of rows.

Please see below in detail:

I have two tables
Table A

```
| CompanyID | ProductID | ProductPartsID |
| --------- | --------- | -------------- |
| 123       |  ert      |   q1234        |
| 234       |  dfr      |    u678        |
| 234       |  dfr      |   Jdsdj        |
| 234       |  dfr      |   Eewe         |
| 234       |  dfr      |   dssd         |
| 234       |  HJU      |   iui89        |
| 234       |  HJU      |   dfsfs        |
| 675       |  gfd      |   654          |
| 675       |  tyh      |   765          |
```

Table B

```
|CompanyID | ProductID |
|--------- |-----------|  
| 123      |  ert      |                
| 234      |  dfr      |                 
| 234      |  HJU      |          
| 675      |  gfd      |                            
| 709      |  tgh      |                  
| 780      |  789      |
```

**Resultset**

Both tables has millions of records in reality.

```
|CompanyID | #ofTableAProductPartsID | #ofTableBProductPartsID |
|--------- |-------------------------|-------------------------|
|  123     |     1                   |       1                 |
|  234     |     6                   |       2                 |
|  675     |     2                   |       1                 |
```

e.t.c
Table B does not have ProductPartsID, but it can be taken from TableA for ProductID from TableB.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only the database you are really using.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far as well.

Comment: Table B doesn't have a product parts column.

Comment: Product parts we need to get from Table A joining on Product ID. I am using SQL server and very new to query writing. Any help any direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

using left join and group by :

```
SELECT
    t.CompanyID
    , COUNT(t.ProductPartsID)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT t2.ProductID)
FROM
    TABLE1           AS t
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
           AND t.ProductID = t2.ProductID
GROUP BY
    t.CompanyID
```

Comment: Thanks! this query is counting productID from table 2, any suggestion how can I get count of productpartID from table one with matching table 2 productIDs.

Comment: You just explain what this query does ! Not sure why it’s not the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   with TableAPartsCount as
     (
         select 
         A.CompanyID, 
         count(A.ProductID) as #ofTableAProductPartsID
         from TableA A
         group by A.CompanyID
     )
     ,TableBPartsCount as 
     (
         select 
             CompanyID, 
             count(ProductID) as #ofTableBProductPartsID
         from TableB 
         group by CompanyID
     )
    
     select 
         A.CompanyID,
         A.#ofTableAProductPartsID,
         B.#ofTableBProductPartsID 
     from TableBPartsCount B 
     join TableAPartsCount A on 
     A.CompanyID = B.CompanyID
```